# How to Pass on Touches of a View to It's Parent Map

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

To indicate distance I draw a circle on top of MKMapview.

The problem is that circle get in the way of MKMapview. When that circle is around I can't easily zoom in or zoom out MKMapview.

How can I tell that cirlce to just pass all touch events to the parent namely MKMapview.

Comment: how did u draw the circle? UIView?

Comment: My programmer did it. Basically we put another UIView on top of MKMapview. It doesn't have to be a circle. It could be a picture of Micky Mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your circle is an instance of UIView you can simple disable user interaction on it:

```
circle.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

that way the circle won't receive any touch events and the mapView will handle them.

Comment: This might not be what you want: "When set to NO, user events—such as touch and keyboard—intended for the view are ignored and removed from the event queue".

Comment: they are not actually removed, the view underneath receives the touches, you can easily test that.

Comment: This is the solution I actually tried and work. @Julien, yes it works as myellow said.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `UIView` method:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

From `-hitTest:withEvent:` documentation:

"If pointInside:withEvent: returns YES, then the subview’s hierarchy is traversed; otherwise, its branch of the view hierarchy is ignored."